# remove 0.0 and not 0 from dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing different values of which when they are unknown are put to 0.0,
I want to remove the columns which contain these values. However in the dataframe some values equal 0 which are valid and should remain untouched.
Is it possible to select only 0.0 values in the dataframe and not 0 values?

Comment: What do you consider to be the difference between `0.0` and `0`?

Comment: 0.0 are considered as unknown while 0 is a value inserted into the dataframe.

Comment: the dataframe contains over a hundred features te do machine learning on . at the moment i am busy with cleaning up the data and therefore i want to remove the 0.0 values which are given to be unknown. a zero is used in some cases when there are two options for a feature and a 0 and 1 is used to represent this . therefore i want to keep these features

Comment: Please post a copy / section of your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter and isinstance to do this. The only difference between 0.0 and 0 is that 0 is an integer and 0.0 is not.

```
my_list = [0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0]
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), my_list))
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```